# Standard Filters for Report

Tags: apex, reporting, metadata

I've been doing some work on gathering info from a report using its metadata in apex. In this picture is basically what I want to extract:

[image]

Currently, I am confused as to why my method for getting the standard filters is returning nothing. Below is my code on what I have so far.

```
// Get the report ID and folderName
List <Report> reportInfo = [SELECT ID, FolderName FROM Report where Name = 'Some New Report'];

// Get report ID
String reportId = (String)reportInfo.get(0).get('Id');

// Use report ID to get report Metadata
Reports.ReportMetadata metadata = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId).getReportMetadata();

// this line is the problem
System.debug('Standard Filters: ' + metadata.getStandardFilters());
```

The very last line simply returns `()` . I tried adding `getName()` and `getValue()` to the end of it but it gives me an error. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're using [standard filters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_StandardFilter.htm#apex_class_reports_StandardFilter) in that report? There's `getStandardDateFilters` for start/end date and date ranges and `getReportFilters()` for each custom filter in the report.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. I have also added a picture as to what info I am trying to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have **zero** [standard filters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_StandardFilter.htm#apex_class_reports_StandardFilter) on that report.

> Standard filters **vary by report type**. For example, standard filters
> for reports on the Opportunity object are Show, Opportunity Status,
> and Probability.

Based on your screenshot,

- **Show Me** is `scope` which you can see in the [Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm) metadata. You can get this with [`getScope()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#apex_reports_ReportMetadata_getScope)

> Defines the scope of data on which you run the report. For example,
> whether you want to run the report against all opportunities,
> opportunities you own, or opportunities your team owns. Valid values
> depend on the reportType. For example, for Accounts reports:
>
> - MyAccounts
> - MyTeamsAccounts
> - AllAccounts

- **Created Date**, as it's a date filter that was provided with the report automatically, will be returned by [`getStandardDateFilters()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#apex_reports_ReportMetadata_getStandardDateFilter) which has a distinction from standard filters.

> Contains information about standard date filter available in the
> report—for example, the API name, start date, and end date of the
> standard date filter duration as well as the API name of the date
> field on which the filter is placed.

Any other filters you customize on that report will be retrieved with [`getReportFilters()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#apex_Reports_ReportMetadata_getReportFilters)

Comment: Great, thanks for the help.